# Are there any best open source BI and i wanna host that BI on any server?

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence

I am looking for a BI Tool for basically good vicualization and report generation.

I need below features to be basic needs of my requirement.

1. Open Source
2. Need to access any database using their credentials and host.
3. Able to host in any server
4. I can APIs to get data

Please suggest me which one will be the good one to go with

Answer (score 0):

I think  Pentaho is the best bi  tool that you can find free of charge. Check their site Web for more details.

Hope that helps!